# the best overload method is match for the string.split(some parameters[]) has invalid arguments

Tags: c#, .net, string, split, character

I'm getting error at mMSH.Split("|")(6).ToUpper; and mMSA_ACK.Split("|")[2].ToUpper(); and CheckNullString(mMSA_ACK.Split("|")[1]) saying that the best overload method is match for the string.split(some parameters[]) has invalid arguments. 
Please help me in this, below is my code.

```
private int FindMSH(string strMessage_ACK, string mMsh_Send) {    
    try {
        //MsgBox("FindMSH")
        writeMessage("Inside FindMSH function");
        //-> get current MSH segment 

        string[] mSplittxt = strMessage_ACK
            .Replace(System.Convert.ToChar(11).ToString(),"")
            .Replace(System.Convert.ToChar(28).ToString(), "")
            .Split(System.Convert.ToChar(13));

        string mMSH_ACK = mSplittxt
            .Where(x => x.ToString().StartsWith("MSH|"))
            .Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault().ToString();

        string mMSA_ACK = mSplittxt
            .Where(x => x.ToString().StartsWith("MSA|"))
            .Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault().ToString();

        //1.ackcode(1) = "AA" in MSA segment


        string sendMSH_msgid = mMSH.Split("|")(6).ToUpper;
        string mAck = string.Empty;
        string recACK_msgid = string.Empty;

        if (mMSA_ACK.Length > 0)
        {
            recACK_msgid = mMSA_ACK.Split("|")[2].ToUpper();
            mAck = CheckNullString(mMSA_ACK.Split("|")[1]);
        }
```

Comment: it is a very basic syntax. If you searched on net you would come to know.

Answer (score 6):

An indexer is used with square brackets and if you want to split on a single character, use a single character. If you want to call a function, use brackets:

```
mMSH.Split('|')[6].ToUpper();
```

This is basic syntax really, you should get a good book or tutorial.

Comment: Thanks friends for all ur suggestions.